How to ignore case but not diacritics with Python regex?
I'm working with a set of regex patterns that I have to match in a target text.
My problematic regex is something like this: (İg)[[:punct:][:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+
Initially, I noticed that Python’s re package doesn’t support character classes like [:punct:]. Then I discovered that with the regex library (instead of re), these forms would actually be supported.
The problem now is that, with both re and regex, enabling IGNORECASE it seems to also ignore diacritics (that I want to consider). For example:
#import re
import regex as re

active_patterns = ["(İg)[[:punct:][:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+"]
text = "A big problem"

for pattern in active_patterns:
    compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    for match in compiled_pattern.finditer(text):
        print(match)

In this code, I want to ignore case but not diacritics. However, it seems that regex library ignore diacritics when IGNORECASE is enabled. Indeed this snippet will print "ig problem". The same behaviour happens with re library if I remove not supported parts, so with the regex (İg). It will print only ig in that case.
Is there a way in Python to make the regex ignore case but keep diacritics intact?

An everlasting Turkish issue. Python lowercases the dotted İ to i\u0307, so the problem is more with how Python lowercases that character rather than with the re/regex libraries. So, the only way I see how to fix the issue is to use an alternation in the regex, (?:İ|i̇), and forget about the re.I.

The problem will remain with the other characters. You might wrap them into case insensitive groups, (?i:...).  See the Python demo.

Thanks @WiktorStribiżew in my real case I have a list of regexes and this is only one of them. I could add a custom handling of this one, by removing the re.IGNORECASE. Do you think that in the normal cases a simple re.IGNORECASE can consider other kinds of diacritics or it always should normalize characters ?

I can't guarantee it will always work like you expect. We have the issue with Turkish, and we also have a lot of issues with Greek, too. Removing the flag will result in false negatives. If the patterns are "manual", you can re-write the way I suggested above. If you create the pattern from a list of words, it is still possible to write the code that will prepare the pattern. BTW, [[:punct:][:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+ is roughly the same as [\W_]+[^\W_]+.

may I suggest adding the [tag:regex] tag?

You could prepend all patterns with (?i) maybe instead of using re.IGNORECASE as attribute?

@PaoloMagnani, I'd be inclinded to use the pattern (?i)(([iİ]|i̇)g)[[:punct:][:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+. Many regex engines use simple case-folding which means İ will only match İ. Python's re module doesn't use simple or full case-folding for case insensitivity, instead they use their own mappings. The behaviour between the re and regex odules differs for these characters. A full mapping if case folding and case mapping between i, i̇. ı, I, and İ is quite complex.
